# Redirección cuando esta logueado en react js

Tags: reactjs

Buen día, Estoy implementando un login que después de obtener los credenciales del usuario que se le redirija al home y que no pueda ver el login
luego de ser logueado. Descubrí que hay useHistory de hooks, Redirect de  ReactDOM funcionan en el mismo componente  pero deseo que el código se pueda usar en cualquier componente pero la redirección  no me funciona.
Este es el código que debería redireccionar en cualquier componente.

```
export const logged_in= () => {
        Cookies.set('logged_in', true, {expires: 128400, sameSite: 'lax'})
        history.push('/home');
}
export const is_logged_in=()=>{
       let logueado=Cookies.get('logged_in')
       if(logueado){
       }else{
            return 
            <Redirect to:"/login"/>
        }
}

'''
```

Intente con  Usehistory y redirect pero usehistory no puedo usarla en esta función por el comportamiento del hook , ni tampoco redirect. Cómo solucionan esto o que utilizan o estoy dejando pasar.
De antemano muchas gracias.

> Cookies librería que encontré para trabajar con cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que podrias hacer es utilizar simplemente el componente Route de `react-route-dom`,

```
//si hay usuario
<Route path='/home' render={()=> isUser ? <HomeScreen/> : <Redirect to="/login"/>} />
//si no hay usuario
<Route path='/login' render={()=> !isUser ? <LoginScreen/> : <Redirect to="/home"/>} />
```

Comment: ¿Esto sería utilizando el estado? por que si es así al recargar la página el estado desaparece.

Comment: deberias organizar el estado dependiendo de donde guardes la sesion, en tu caso estas utilizando cookies, deberias agregar algun spinner para hacerle saber al usuario que esta cargando la pagina, mietras carga puedes agregarle a la variable `isUser` true o false dependiendo de si hay sesion o no, me explico ?

Comment: No olvides votar a favor de la respuesta si a solucionado tu problema, recuerda que futuros usuarios pueden estar teniendo el mismo problema y con ello ayudarías a que encuentren una solución un poco mas fácil